# How to "extract" nodes in a linked list between two indices in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to write a function that extracts notes between index x and index y and have the option to leave the original list unmodified or modify it such that the extracted nodes are deleted. The function is to return a listed list with the extracted nodes.

My current strategy is to duplicate the linked list using a helper function then use a delete function `void delete (struct node * head, int x, int y);` to do the required deletions on both lists (original and list to be returned).

Is this a good strategy or is it too inefficient? I am looking for O(n) if possible but this looks like O(n^2).

struct implementaiton:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *last;
}
```

The two functions I want to write are:

```
struct node *extract1(struct node *head, int x, int y);
// extract1 modifies original list.
struct node *extract2(struct node *head, int x, int y);
// extract2 does not modify original list.
```

My delete function mentioned above is tested and works as required.

```
struct node *extract1 (struct node *head, int x, int y){
    int currPos = 0;
    int len = length(head);
    struct node *curr = head;

    // I removed error checked for out of range indices for brevity

    struct node *copy = duplicate(stuct node *head);

    delete(curr, x, y); // modify original list

    // modify new list

    struct node *curr = copy;

    while (curr != NULL && currPos != x){ // traverse to x index
        delete(curr, 0, x);
        curr = curr->next;
        currPos++;
    }

    while (curr != NULL && currPos != y){ // traverse to x index
        delete(curr, y, len-1);
        curr = curr->next;
        currPos++;
    }

    return copy;
}
```

`extract2` is similar but lacks the line `delete(curr, x, y);`

I think this is a horrible approach especially in terms of complexity.
Can you lead me in the correct direction as to how I should approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pointers-to-pointers will simplify the problem. I t will also allow you to cut out the first node in the chain (without dummy nodes or backpointers)

- no copying is done, the subchain is physically removed
- and returned

---

```
        /* Extract part of a linked list.
        **      skip is the number of nodes to skip (skip==0 means: the first node is also extracted)
        **      stop is position of the node *after* extracted part
        **      (so: skip=0,stop=1 will extract one node: the first)
        */
struct llist *llist_extract(struct llist **pp, unsigned skip, unsigned stop)
{
unsigned pos;
struct llist *result = NULL, **rpp;

if (stop <= skip) return NULL;

        /* Advance pointer2p `skip` positions  */
for (pos= 0; *pp; pp= &(*pp)->next) {
        if (pos >= skip ) break;
        pos++;
        }

        /* Now, *pp points to the first node to delete,
        ** it is also the start of the chain to return.
        ** And: *pp is the place to re-attach the trailing part of the ll
        */
result = *pp;
for ( rpp = pp; *rpp; rpp = &(*rpp)->next) {
        if (pos++ >= stop ) break;
        }
*pp = *rpp ;    /* append remainder to initial part */
*rpp = NULL;    /* terminate the extracted part */
return result;
}
```

---

Test rig:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct llist {
        struct llist *next;
        char *payload;
        };

struct llist lists[] =
{{ lists+1, "one" }
,{ lists+2, "two" }
,{ lists+3, "three" }
,{ lists+4, "four" }
,{ lists+5, "five" }
,{ lists+6, "six" }
,{ lists+7, "seven" }
,{ lists+8, "eight" }
,{ lists+9, "nine" }
,{ NULL, "ten" }
        };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct llist *root,*tmp;
unsigned start=0, stop=0;

if (argc >=2) sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &start);
if (argc >=3) sscanf(argv[2], "%u", &stop);

root = lists;
fprintf(stdout, "## %s\n", "initial:" );
for (tmp=root; tmp; tmp=tmp->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", tmp->payload);
        }

fprintf(stdout, "## extract(%u..%u)\n", start,stop );
tmp = llist_extract(&root, start, stop);

for (; tmp; tmp=tmp->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", tmp->payload);
        }

fprintf(stdout, "## %s\n", "Rest." );
for (tmp=root; tmp; tmp=tmp->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", tmp->payload);
        }
fprintf(stdout, "## %s\n", "done." );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, this solution doesn't modify original list, correct?

Comment: Yes it does. It actually cuts out a part of the chain, and retains the rest. (you could compile & execute to verify)

Comment: How can I modify it such that it does the same thing without modifying the original list?

Answer (score 3):

You are using 2 concepts that are mutually exclusive in your approach. Usually, when using linked list, you don't need indexes. You need indexes when your use arrays. In your approach, you are using the linked lists, but you are also using indexes as if the linked list was an array, and so it brings more complexity.

1. If you really need indexes, can you consider using arrays ? In such case, a single *memmove()* would solve your problem with arrays.
2. If you want to stick with linked lists, can you consider using something different than indexes ? A mere example would be to use a pointer to the *starting linked_list_element*, and a pointer to the *ending linked_list_element* that would replace your *x* and *y* indexes in the implementation you proposed.

Comment: What if I have to stick to this approach? Is there a way I can do the extraction and deletion without explicitly using the indices, i.e. not treating x and y as such.

Comment: I forgot to mention, in my linked list implementation, i do have a pointer to first and a pointer to last node. I will add this information to question if it helps.

Comment: It depends on how you did get the indices. If you got them by previously browsing the linked_list, simply replace the x index by a pointer to the node which is at position x. By doing so (i.e. using x and y as a node pointers), you will have the *extract()* function be o(1), which is faster and constant whatever the linked_list's size.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what that means. x and y are just integers given by user, how can I use them as nodes?